# collapsing toolbar layout with 2 tab layout in android

Tags: android

With **CollapsingToolbarLayout** i want to show two tabs one after another.

This is my layout file.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/detail_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="@dimen/article_keylines"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/md_keylines"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/thankyou"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/tabs2"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                android:elevation="6dp"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Collapsing is working fine, but it is not showing any of the tab layouts.

What needs to be corrected in above file.

Comment: where is your code??

Answer (score 0):

first of all you are writing two type `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to create Two different Tab. so first of all remove that. and make `ViewPager` for that. like below way.

```
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

so Change your code to below as I set up your XML.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/detail_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="@dimen/article_keylines"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/md_keylines"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/thankyou"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/tabs2"
                />

          </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/zxing_transparent"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="50dip"
            app:collapsedTitleGravity="top|center_vertical"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/collapseTitle">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:alpha="0.5"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dip"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:titleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.Title"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                >

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:paddingTop="5dip"
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabGravity="center"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dip"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/NavigationTabTextAppeareance"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:background="@color/semiwhite"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="90dip"
        android:layout_height="90dip"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/selected"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/black"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is working , you can try. This one even has Navigation drawer

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context="com.example.abhinav.tsdhub.MainActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mainActivityCollapsingBar"
        app:titleEnabled="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/toolbarImage"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:src="@drawable/scribbled"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="43dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabTextColor="#d6cece"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffffff"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
            app:tabContentStart="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/main_viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_body"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


        <!--navigation drawer attributes
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"/>
    -->

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```